# G++ compilation error "cc1plus" not found

Tags: c++, g++

I think I accidentally deleted a couple files from my machine, and now G++ won't compile.
I tried to `apt-get remove` it then `apt-get install` it to see if it would fix it, but it didn't work. Now I have no clue at all how to get G++ working again.

Here is the error:

```
g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 Precise ARM version.

Answer (score 11):

You need to run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall g++-4.6`. Just reinstalling the `g++` package won't work, as it's a meta-package which simply depends on the versioned packages instead.

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu, the `g++` package is a 'dependency package' that installs the default version of g++ for your OS version (e.g. g++-4.6 for 12.04) so reinstalling the g++ package may not re-install the files you deleted - you probably need to reinstall the underlying g++-*N.m* package.

You can find out what the actual default package is by executing `apt-cache depends g++` or by following the g++ symlink using `ls -l $(which g++)`. Alternatively you could use `readlink` to follow the link automatically e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(readlink $(which g++))
```